# Wordpress: Different loop for different categories on frontpage

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I get a bug in my design when I use different loops for different categories. [Check out live preview here](http://inmyownview.com/wordpress). The "WISHWISHWISH: WHEN IN STOCKHOLM" post is under the same category as "FASHIONTOAST: SPACE CAMP", but the tag "blogger outfit for dagen" goes to the top of the page on the post last mentioned! It's supposed to go under the image for the post, like it does on "WISHWISHWISH: WHEN IN STOCKHOLM". Why does this happen?

My codes:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="columns">
<div id="frontpage" class="clearfix">   

    <?php 
    query_posts('posts_per_page=9' . '&orderby=date'); 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if ( in_category( 'Streetstyle' )) {
        if(condition){ ?>
            <div <?php post_class('pin'); ?>>
                <div class="reader-look">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } 
                    ?> 
                    <div class="clearfix"><tag>Streetstyle</tag></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
    } elseif ( in_category( array( 'blogger-outfit' ) )) { //du kan også bruke komma her eks: 'streetstyle', 'ukategorisert'
        if(condition){ ?>
                <div class="reader-look">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } 
                    ?> 
                    <div class="clearfix"><tag>Blogger Outfit For dagen</tag></div>
                    </a>
                </div>

        <?php }
     }
     elseif ( in_category( array( 'video' ) )) { //du kan også bruke komma her eks: 'streetstyle', 'ukategorisert'
        if(condition){ ?>
                <div class="reader-look">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } 
                    ?> 
                    <div class="clearfix"><tag>Video</tag></div>
                    </a>
                </div>

        <?php }
      }
     elseif ( in_category( array( 'tips' ) )) { //du kan også bruke komma her eks: 'streetstyle', 'ukategorisert'
        if(condition){ ?>
                <div class="reader-look">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } 
                    ?> 
                    <div class="clearfix"><tag>Fashion tips</tag></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
        <?php }
      }
     else {
        if(condition){ ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div <?php post_class('pin'); ?>>
                <h1>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h1>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
                the_content(' '); ?> 
            </div>
        </a>
    <?php } }
    ?>          
    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
    #wrapper #frontpage {
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}
#wrapper #columns {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin { 
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid; 
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
    column-break-inside: avoid; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 360px;
    font: 100 12.5px 'Helvetica';
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.reader-look h1  {
    text-shadow: white 1px 1px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font: 100 24px 'Lato';
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.reader-look h1 a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.reader-look img {
    width: 360px;
    height: auto !important;
}
tag {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font: 100 16px 'Lato';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin .more-link {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin img {
    width: 360px;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin iframe {
    width: 380px !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin h1  {
    text-shadow: white 1px 1px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font: 100 24px 'Lato';
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin h1 a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper #columns .pin a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper .pin .heading {
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper .pin .heading h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  font: 100 21px 'Lato';
  position:relative;
  top: 12px;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allow the column to break inside the reader-look. Add this to your CSS:

```css
.reader-look{
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid; 
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
    column-break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

And you are good on the browsers that supports it.

Comment: But the "FASHIONTOAST: SPACE CAMP" is the oldest one, but it now stands beside the newest one, and thats not correct?

Comment: The CSS columns you are currently using does not know what is new or old, what is good or bad. It just takes all your `<div class="reader-look">` and break them up into three columns where it thinks is a good place, not where you think it's a good place. If you want to be able to set which articles goes where you need to rethink your design and probably create your own columns or start breaking the columns yourself.

Comment: To be more precise: it takes all your content inside of `#columns` and make it into three columns, only respecting not to break inside something that has the class `.pin`. Your `.reader-look` didn't, therefor the CSS broke it and made the text show in the second column. My code made the `.reader-look` not to break in columns to prevent it, therefor the whole article moved up to column two since the CSS decided it was the best way to present the three columns of `#columns`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for taking time to answer my questions. But, how will I be able to let Wordpress decide witch post goes where in the columns? And what other way is it to create my own columns and make it work like this?

Comment: This is hard for me to write down in a comment (or an answer for that matter) on stackoverflow and since you don't have enough points we can't chat. But maybe we can use quakenet? Go here, http://webchat.quakenet.org/, add a nick and join the channel #stackoverflow. I'll give you 15 mins to get in before I leave.

Comment: After a long chat (still going strong) it will be masonry for jQuery that will take care of the whole shebangs!