# Wordpress: Best way to sort posts in columns

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, grid

I'm trying to make an online magazine in WordPress. Where every post is shown in different columns. The first one in column one is the latest posted one, in column two, the second last and column three the third last and so on. How is the best way to do this? I want to prevent any gaps between the posts, so they follow each other perfectly and it looks nice. I have tried -moz-column stuff, and it works fine, but the posts are not ordered by date, just how CSS finds it appropriate to display the posts. Is there a way I can do this?

[You can se live preview of my blog here.](http://inmyownview.com/wordpress)

So far: 
CSS

```
#wrapper #columns {
}
#wrapper #columns .col {
    width: 360px;
    background: red;
}
```

PHP:

```
<div id="columns" class="clearfix">
    <?php 
        query_posts('posts_per_page=9' . '&orderby=date'); 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    ?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="reader-look">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
            } 
            ?> 
            <div class="clearfix"><tag>Blogger Outfit For dagen</tag></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373422/wordpress-different-loop-for-different-categories-on-frontpage for the correct answer to this question!

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left;` to `#wrapper #columns .col` and also add this rule:

```
.col:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: – Thank you, but there are still gaps if you check the live preview.

Comment: You mean you want them all to have the same height?

Comment: No, the height will depend on the content of the post. I want the posts to go under each other, and not have white gaps like it shows on the  live preview(http://inmyownview.com/wordpress).

Comment: This is how it looks once I make the changes I mentioned in my answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/7npI0.jpg - if you don't want them to be the same height, then what gaps are you referring to?

Comment: Between the two tall pictures of the women, there is a small post. Under the post there is a white area, I don't want to have that white gap there. I want the post to come right under the one above.